# Simple Cross Platform Clipboard Library?

Tags: c++, c

I was wondering if one was out there. Really all I need is a way to copy and paste strings, like from game to Notepad and vice versa.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry you didn't find what you were looking for. Perhaps you should simply rephrase the question to "how to I implement clipboard for text on a Mac" if that's the only piece of information you're missing

Comment: I've created a cross-platform C++ library that you might find useful: https://github.com/dacap/clip (Windows and macOS, Linux/X11 isn't available yet)

Comment: @dacap nice library! Hope you can add Linux support :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each application has to provide support for it. Notepad does. If you want *your* application to provide it, then *you* have to implement it. Luckily this is easy if you're using the right tools.

Cross-platform programming frameworks, such as Qt, usually have classes that encapsulate clipboard operations across platforms.

Using Qt as an example, you have the [QClipboard](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qclipboard.html) class which makes it as simple as calling `setText()` to set the clipboard's textual contents and `text()` to get them. There are also methods for images and other data formats - just check the docs.

Comment: Unfortunately QT is a bit overkill for my needs, I was thinking something small and lite.

Comment: @Milo: overkill how - in terms of DLL size? Note that QClipboard really has no dependencies, you can just use this class from Qt and nothing else. Although I suspect that if you're writing a cross-platform application, you may want to use more of it

Comment: No I'm writing a game and just need it for my TextBox

Comment: @Milo: The clipboard is not "small and light" -- if you want simple text then you can write the 3 lines of code required to put text on and off the clipboard for each platform you want to support and stick them behind `#ifdefs`. However the clipboard has complicated things like [OLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding) which are attached to it, which are going to require huge libraries to get right in cross platform manner. (For example, pasting an Excel table into a Word document -- Excel has to provide a COM component that tells Word how to handle that object....

Comment: @Billy ONeal Well that 3 lines of code is what I meant, I was wondering if something like that existed so I don't have to deal with Objective C and NS on Mac.

Comment: @Milo: I just found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270243/os-independent-clipboard-copy-paste-text-in-c which asked something similar but also didn't reach a resolution