# How to get a string in a copy?

Tags: c++, string, clipboard, copy-paste

For example, I have a string, with some words. Is there some way to copy it to the clipboard? Like I run the program, and it automatically copies it to the clipboard, so I can just go on somewhere and paste it.

Comment: Take a look at [autohotkey](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/autohotkey/info). Read the documentation and try to code a program, don't be afraid to ask a question if you get stuck in the process.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270243/os-independent-clipboard-copy-paste-text-in-c/2270305#2270305

Comment: That's going to be *very* platform dependent. Some platforms have multiple unrelated (and bloody un-controllable and un-synchronizable) clipboards (like my Linux workstation), others have none at all (like my toaster). Consult your platform's documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the operating system that you are trying to do this in. Linux and windows have slightly different ways of doing this.

I am assuming you are trying to write a program that will be able to move variable information to the clipboard to allow a user to paste it where they want.

Windows

Here is a link that has an example of a c++ program that uses the clipboard:
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80db3kax.aspx)

Linux

Linux is a little more complicated. It depends on the specific distro and what clipboard you want to move information to and from. There are a couple popular command line programs that could help you out.

XClip will copy and paste information to or from the command line, and you can use it with a pipe to do a lot of things.

Here is another question very similar to yours [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881230/copy-data-from-the-clipboard-on-linux-mac-and-windows-with-a-single-python-scri)

Comment: Big Thank you!! After 40 minutes got it working! This is the best thing ever!